# Does gRPC work with Universal Windows App?

Tags: windows-runtime, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am able to use gRPC within a C# desktop application.
I tried to install the nuget gRPC package for a WUA but I got a lot of errors:

```
Grpc.Core 1.1.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64)
```

and I could not install it. Is there any implementation for WinRT?

Comment: It does work nowadays as is proven by Diederik Krols in https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2019/07/02/getting-started-with-grpc-in-uwp-and-asp-net-core/ (Thank you Diederik) I used this as an example for our own solution, where we keep the grpc proxy generated code in a .Net standard 2.0 library. It is pretty straightforward to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, gRPC C# currently doesn't support Universal Windows Applications. We support desktop .NET45+ and netstandard1.5+ (and therefore also ASP.NET core).
Please see https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/8636 for more details.